# SQL returns null rows even if the data is present within the database

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

so I have a session variable which fetches the information from login and through which I would like to display the data.I tried any ways but this always returns null.data is being stored in phpmyadmin,but when I run the sql query within phpmyadmin it again returns null.

php:

```
<?php

$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="";
$db="bhprj";
session_start();

$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);
$var =  $_SESSION['en'];
$sql = "select * from PB where mailid = '{$_SESSION['en']}';";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
```

```html
<div class="input-field">
    <p>SOURCE</p><br> 
    <input type="text" name="sn" value="<?php echo $result['source']; ?>" required>
</div>
<div class="input-field">
    <p> destination </p> <br>
    <input type="text" name="dn" value="<?php echo $result['destination']; ?>" required>
</div>
<div class="input-field">
    <p>NO OF PASSENGERS </p><br><br> 
    <input type="number" name="nn" value="<?php echo $result['nop']; ?>" required>
</div>

<div class="input-field">
    <p>DATE</p><br><br> 
    <input type="date" name="date" value="<?php echo $result['date']; ?>" required>
</div>
```

hoping for a help.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing your SQL query like this:

`$sql = "select * from PB where mailid = ". {$_SESSION['en']};`